# XPath not working properly when the root tag got xmlns property

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse an xml file using XPath

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(File);

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr 
     = xpath.compile("//PerosnList/List/Person");
```

It took me alot of time to see that it's not working cause the root element got xmlns attribute
once i remove the attr it works fine!, how can i workaround this xlmns attr without deleting it from the file ?

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/vsDal.Entities">
.....
....
<PersonList>
...
<List>
<Person></Person>
<Person></Person>
<Person></Person>
</List>
</PersonList>
</Root>
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: you had a typo in the xpath compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide a [`NamespaceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) and namespace your expression. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to add this code
 NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContextMap(
        "foo", "http://foo", 
        "bar", "http://bar",
        "def", "http://def");
But seems like the compiler doesnt know this class : NamespaceContextMap , do i need some Jar for this ?
Thanks

Comment: From the linked post: __Unfortunately, there are no implementations of NamespaceContext provided in the standard library (well, there is one in StAX but it is of limited utility).__ The NamespaceContextMap implementation is at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 10):

The `xmlns` attribute is more than just a regular attribute. It is a [namespace attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces) which are used to uniquely qualify elements and attributes.

The `PersonList`, `List`, and `Person` elements "inherit" that namespace. Your XPath isn't matching because you are selecting elements in the "no namespace". In order to address elements bound to a namespace in XPath 1.0 you must define a namespace-prefix and use it in your XPath expression.

**You could make your XPath more generic and just match on the `local-name`, so that it matches  the elements regardless of their namespace:**

```
//*[local-name()='PersonList']/*[local-name()='List']/*[local-name()='Person']
```